# return json response in services directly

Tags: php, symfony

i want to return jsonReponse in service directly without return just json to my method in controller

this is my method in controller and i want to show response with status = 200 and finished :

```
/**
 * @Route("/ab", name="ab")
 */

public function abTest()
{
    $this->service->serviceIndex();
    return new JsonResponse(['status'=>208,'result'=>"RIGHT"],208);
}
```

this is my service:

```
class serviceTest
{
    public function serviceIndex()
    {
        return new JsonResponse(['status'=>200,'result'=>"ok"],200);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, `return $this->service->serviceIndex()`?

Comment: @Jonnix i use this line of code in my api without any variable . i dont want to get json from service in controller and so on . i want to have final return in service

Comment: Why? You can't do that without an exit / die, but then you lose all the stuff Symfony does after the controller action. So basically, just use return as is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't want that. That is precisely why the separation between services and controllers exist. You may use a service in other circumstances as well (e.g. call it from other services), in which case you do not want any sort of automatic JSON response. Services are *internal*. Controllers are the interface between the "outside world" and your internals, so it's exactly the controller's job to adapt whatever the service returns to whatever is appropriate for the outside world (JSON/HTML/text/whatever).